The order of $\langle(1~ 2~ 3~ 4~ 5~ 6~ 7~ 8~ 9~ 10 ~11), (2~ 10)(3~ 4)(5~ 9)(6~ 7)\rangle$
I want to determine the order of the subgroup of $S_{11}$ mentioned in the title. I have shown that this group is doubly transitive and contains subgroups of order $6$ fixing $1$ and $2$. Therefore, if it can be demonstrated that elements of this group fixing $1$, $2$, and $3$ are the identity element, then it can be shown that the order is $660$.

I'm guessing you don't want to use that this subgroup is isomorphic to $PSL(2,11)$?

I didn't notice that. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

If you just want to determine its order, then you should use GAP or Magma (or Sage), which will tell you immediately that the order is $660$, and also that it is isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$. Of course if this is a homework exercise then you will need a different approach, but I'm not sure what.

Thank you for your reply.
